# How to send audio to an ip-camera?

Tags: android, cordova, audio, send, ip-camera

I have a ip camera from Apexis model J011ws, and i'm developing an app to control it, and i've been trying for some days send audio to camera, but i don't know how to do this, i'm using phonegap, i didn't found nothing helpful on internet.

Comment: Sending audio to camera makes no sense. What is actually a task?

Comment: I'm already managing to catch the video from "http://ip:port/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=" now I need to take the microphone audio from the camera, and most importantly, send audio to the camera loudspeaker, sorry for my bad english, this not my main language.